# MYSQL- Simply Query Needs to be Split into Separate Rows for Each Date

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm rather new with sql and have a rather simply query:

```
SELECT
r.code,u.full_name, DATE(m.send_at) as "Date",
COUNT(m.content),
SUM(CASE WHEN m.type = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS "Forward",
SUM(CASE WHEN m.type = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS "Reply",
SUM(CASE WHEN m.type = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS "Note",
SUM(CASE WHEN m.type = 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS "LiveChat"
FROM janus_service_communication.t_comm_message m

LEFT JOIN janus_service_auth.t_auth_user u
ON (REPLACE(REPLACE(m.sender_id, 'QRS:user:', '') , 'DRIVER:user:', '')) = u.id

LEFT JOIN janus_service_auth.t_auth_user_role ur
ON u.id=ur.user_id

LEFT JOIN janus_service_auth.t_auth_role r
ON ur.role_id=r.id
WHERE r.code IS NOT NULL

AND Month(m.send_at)=Month(curdate())
GROUP BY Date(m.send_at);
```

Its output shows individual dates in the Date column, but the counts are actually aggregates. I want to pull this month (to date), and have each date have its own row with all other data alongside. How should I split the dates into individual rows?

Any help would be much appreciated!Thank you!

Comment: That's what `SUM()` and `GROUP BY` are for. If you don't want aggregates, don't do that.

Comment: Please add sample data and the desired result.

Comment: Remove the COUNT, SUM and the GROUP BY at the end